# Building a binary search tree and finding a node in it

Tags: java, tree

I am new to Java so go easy on me, here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication3 {
public static Node root;
ArrayList<Integer> solutionpath = new ArrayList<>();

public JavaApplication3(){

this.root = null;
}

public void insert(int id){
Node newNode = new Node(id);
if(root==null){
root = newNode;
return;
}
Node current = root;
Node parent = null;
while(true){
parent = current;
if(id<current.data){
current = current.left;
if(current==null){
parent.left = newNode;
return;
}
}else{
 current = current.right;
if(current==null){
parent.right = newNode;
return;
}
}
}
}

public void backtrack(int data) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
  data = input.nextInt();
// Start at the top of the tree
Node focusNode = root;
// While we haven't found the Node
// keep looking
while (focusNode.data != data) {
solutionpath.add(focusNode.data); 
// If we should search to the left
if (data < focusNode.data) {

// Shift the focus Node to the left child
focusNode = focusNode.left;  
} else {
// Shift the focus Node to the right child
focusNode = focusNode.right;
}
// The node wasn't found

if (focusNode == null)
System.out.println("not exist ");
}
System.out.println(focusNode.data);
System.out.println(solutionpath);
}   

public void display(Node root){
if(root!=null){
display(root.left);
System.out.println(" " + root.data);
display(root.right);
}
}

public void run(){
  int x;
  JavaApplication3 a = new JavaApplication3();
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
  System.out.println("enter desired number of nodes: ");
  x = input.nextInt();
  while(x > 0){
     int y;
     System.out.println("enter a node: ");
     y = input.nextInt();
  a.insert(y);
  x--;
  }
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     JavaApplication3 b = new JavaApplication3();

 b.run();
 b.display(root);  
 System.out.println("backtrack a Node: ");
 b.backtrack(0);
     }
   }
```

Not perfect i know but still working. How can I make this code better?

Comment: While we can review your existing code and help you to improve it, Code Review is not the place to ask for changing the behavior such as "print tree in form of levels" or "don't want to accept duplicate inputs".

Comment: well then improve my code or save it for your self , i said am new to this this even is my first question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because author is not looking for a review.

Comment: I edited your question to be asking "How can I make this code better?" I believe that it works, while it might not have all the features that you want for the future, I think it has sufficient features to be considered working. I hope you will find value in any possible answers you might get.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an IDE to indent your code properly so that you can properly read it. As it, the code is very hard to read. Most if not all IDE's will have shortcuts for this - if you're going to learn one shortcut (aside from copy, cut, paste and undo), it should be that one.

As for your code - why does `backtrack` take an int parameter when you overwrite it with a number read from a scanner anyway?